# Exception "Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Product' "

Tags: maven, drools, dsl

That problem is solved but the in the main class rules are firing. But the drl file is not forming.

```
package com.sample;
import com.model.example.Product.*;
expander product.dsl

rule "success"
when 
     There is a Product that 
     -has price greater than 100 
     -has quantity less than 2 
     -has category equal to 'grocery'
then
    success
end
```

I am getting an Exception "Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Product' " in my maven project in which i have created dsl and dslr files.

```
rule "failure"
when 
    There is a Product that 
    -has price less than 100 
    -has quantity greater than 2
    -has category equal to 'medicine'
then
    fail
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The DRL import statement works as in Java. Therefore, import followed by the full class name:

```
import com.model.example.Product;
```